# sqoop import-all-tables - with SQL Server imports system tables

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to use sqoop import-all-tables to get the data from SQL Server into HDFS from a particular database.

After it imports all the expected tables from the DB successfully, it also tries to import system tables in the DB. Is there a way t force sqoop to import only non-system tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a couple of system tables are listed as user tables. Hence the issue.